# React Router on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, react-router

React Router works on Heroku for my MERN app as long as I load index.html before anything else. Client-side routing fails if I go directly to a route in the address bar (e.g., mysite.com/products). However, clicking on a link to the products page from the home page works.

This problem has been [discussed extensively for many years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually), but I can't solve the issue in my environment. Strategies have evolved, and it's not clear what the best situation is at the present date.

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
```

My project structure is:

- `root`

  - `backend`: Express server
  - `frontend`: React App

I tried adding a `static.json` file to the project root.

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "clean_urls": false,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

I also tried handling the routing fallback in Express. After all my routes, I have:

```
const __dirname = path.resolve()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/build')))
} else {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('API is running...')
  })
}

// error handling middleware
// define error-handling middleware last, after other app.use() and routes calls
app.use(notFound) // 404 errors
app.use(errorHandler) // other errors

// for all non-api requests, return index.html from the build directory
app.get('*'),
  (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'))
  }

// server listener
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6060
app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold
  )
)
```

I'd be grateful for the insight into what I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve:

1. Put error-handling middleware last.
2. Set a static path to the build directory
3. Directing all non-API routes to `index.html`

No `static.json` was required. Also, make sure `process.env.NODE_ENV` is set to `production` in Heroku config vars.

```
const __dirname = path.resolve()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/build')))

  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'))
  )
} else {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('API is running....')
  })
}

// error handling middleware
// define error-handling middleware last, after other app.use() and routes calls
app.use(notFound) // 404 errors
app.use(errorHandler) // other errors

// server listener
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6060
app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold
  )
)
```